# Django Admin Panel not showing on production

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have recently deployed project on linux server. I can't access admin panel by going to my-domain/admin. i can view it when running project locally but on production it says "This site can't be reached"

Comment: it could be an issue with the reverse proxy server like NGINX configuration, also you can check the admin site url in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you facing this issue while trying to log in to your admin panel from production?

[image: admin-panel403-error-in-production]

Is this your scenario? If this is the case, you need to edit your `settings.py` file like the following:

```
...
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://<your-site-name>.com']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://<your-site-name>.com']
```

or

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It was because on production, the path to admin is not /admin but whatever is specified in .envs/.production/.django in this line:

```
DJANGO_ADMIN_URL=6Iq4ajyGAnQ0RB789WmzcDoRvLpKB/
```

Going to

```
<my-domain>/6Iq4ajyGAnQ0RB789WmzcDoRvLpKB
```

worked fine. Hope this helps some other beginners